# Handling connection issue between selenium grid hub and node in the test

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I run test using webdriver which run on a remote docker grid. Sometimes , while the test has already grabbed a browser and in middle of run, connection to forward the request fails (probably between hub and node), and then test fails due to this. Is there any elegant way, I can handle such error in the test and retry running the test. I know that the  grid issue is the main problem here, but that issue has to be dealt separately , but I was keen to know how we can handle such errors in the test. I have mentioned how my test and driver factory looks like. Any help will be appreciated. I have also mentioned in the bottom , the error in the grid, due to which test fails, but that error I am not caring much because I am dealing with that grid issue separately.

```java
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void setUpBeforeClass(){
instantiateDriverAndpages(browserName,browserVersion,platform) // grab remote webdriver instance
}

@Test
public void test1(retryAnalyzer = TestBase.class){
// all tests here
// in this part sometimes, test fails because of connection issue with grid
}

public void instantiateDriverAndpages(String browserName, String browserVersion, String platform) throws Exception {

    driverFactory = new DriverFactory();
    driver = driverFactory.get(browserName, browserVersion);

    if (driver == null) {

        throw new WebDriverException("Failed to load Remote WebDriver Instances");
    }
    dr = (RemoteWebDriver) driver;
   }

@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void afterClass() {
    if (driver != null) {
        driver.quit();
    }
    if (dr != null) {
        dr.quit();
    }
}

@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void afterTest(ITestResult result) throws Exception {
    methodName = result.getName();

    if (!result.isSuccess()) {
        log.error("Test  Failed in method " + methodName);
    }

    log.info("After method  {}", methodName);
}
```

Somewhere in Driverfactory class

```java
    public WebDriver get(String browserName, String browserVersion, String platform) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        // Set common webdriver properties
        des = new DesiredCapabilities();
            threadDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();    
            des.setPlatform(Platform.valueOf(platform));
            des.setVersion(browserVersion);
            log.info("Setting cross browser run");

            // set the desired capabilities per browser
            switch (BrowserName.valueOf(browserName)) {
                case FIREFOX:
                    //set firefox cap
                    log.info("Setting FIREFOX browser");
                    break;
                case IE:
                    des.setBrowserName(BrowserType.IE);
                    log.info("Setting IE browser");
                    break;
                case CHROME:
                    des.setBrowserName(BrowserType.CHROME);
                    log.info("Setting CHROME browser");
                    break;

            }

            String seleniumIP="someIp";
            remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(seleniumIP), des);
            remoteWebDriver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
            driver = remoteWebDriver;
            threadDriver.set((RemoteWebDriver) driver);
              return getDriver();
        }


    }
```

Error in grid due to which test fails:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Session [ee1ad4f37] was terminated due to FORWARDING_TO_NODE_FAILED
        at org.openqa.grid.internal.ActiveTestSessions.getExistingSession(ActiveTestSessions.java:116)
        at org.openqa.grid.internal.DefaultGridRegistry.getExistingSession(DefaultGridRegistry.java:389)
        at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.getSession(RequestHandler.java:237)
        at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:122)
        at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:84)
        at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
        at
```

Comment: Why wouldn't a retry analyzer not work for you ?

Comment: because, I think currently what's happening is, when the connection is lost in the middle, the driver doesn't have the browser handle, so I think even if retry of test happen, the test won't execute. I am open for suggestion, I think what I can do, is put the entire test inside try catch and catch the `WebDriverException` for grid error, and whenever this exception happens, I can call `instantiateDriverAndpages` again. What do you think

Comment: I dont think I understand you. When the browser represented by the driver object is lost, you would see exceptions when you try performing operations using the driver object. When exceptions arise, a test method fails and that is when a retry analyzer kicks in. So where exactly is the issue ?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you said, that is , when exception happened  because driver object is lost --> test method fails --> retryAnalyzer kicks in --> but retryAnalyzer tries to start the @Test assuming it already has the driver object. But in reality, driver object is lost. That is what the problem is happening. To solve it, what I though I could do is, catch the "WebdriverException", and handle the connection refused error in catch block, and then again call `instantiateDriverAndpages` method. So, I was looking from you, would this be correct way to do it or you could suggest a better way.

Comment: If your issue is just driver object, then there are multiple ways of solving it. If you leverage a TestNG listener that is responsible for driver creation and making it available via a thread local variable, then your test always will just query the thread local. The other way is you basically create the driver object via a `@BeforeMethod` method, inject it into the `ITestResult` object and then have your `@Test` query it from its `ITestResult` object. Wouldn't that work ?

Comment: Ok, I will try second option. Would be great if you have a basic skeleton handy, but even if it’s not there, I will try it out and let you know. Thanks for your time !